# Is there any way around Typescript's penchant for freezing objects in certain scopes but not others?

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface

I have an interface:

```
interface Model {
  pre: Vertices,
  post: Vertices,
  m: Matrix,
  viewport: Vector,
  halfViewport: Vector,
  mouse: MouseState,
  selection: boolean
}
```

The state object in my app is an instance of Model, the selection property being initialized to false. Note there is no readonly decorator:

```
const state: Model = {
  ...
  selection : false
}
```

For performance purposes, Model values are updated in place since most of the properties are reference types. So there are a few places in the code where properties will be updated, some nested in the call stack.

Now, I'm noticing that in a function at the top scope, its completely legitimate for me to update the Model object's selection property:

function draw(state) {
  state.selection = !state.selection
  ...
}

I don't actually make this call in my code, but its key to note *where* I can modify that selection property, because further down the stack, in a React component event handler, I'll attempt to assign a value to `selection`:

```
function app (S: Model) : DOMElement<HTMLAttributes, Element> {
  const props = {
    ...
    onMouseDown: function (e: MouseEvent) : void {
      ...
      S.selection = false
    }
  }
  return React.DOM.div(props)
}
```

But that assignment throws the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'selection' of object '#<Object>'
```

At first I did a double take and checked I didn't write `readonly` in the `Model` declaration, but I didn't. When I take a look in the Chrome debugger, I discover that the object at `S` is **frozen** (as in, `tsc` calls `Object.freeze' on things. I believe this is related to the excess property checking in TS wherein interface instances get checked for such when assign to variables or parameters, but is there anyway around this? It seems super inconsistent that I can effect a mutation in one scope, but not another.

Answer (score 4):

> I discover that the object at S is frozen (as in, tsc calls `Object.freeze' on things. I believe this is related to the excess property checking in TS wherein interface instances get checked for such when assign to variables or parameters, but is there anyway around this?

Nothing of the sort happens. TypeScript doesn't emit code that calls `Object.freeze`. You can read the emitted JavaScript yourself, of course. TypeScript never does anything except remove type annotations and turn ES6+ constructs to equivalent ES5 code, none of which includes calling `freeze` on random stuff.

Something else has frozen the object. I suspect you might be trying to set a property on a React `state` object instead of correctly calling `setState`, but it's hard to say without a complete example.

Comment: There are absolutely no class components in my code, just stateless functions, so `setState` and class component related matters should be a non-factor.